# Same space between words in multiple lines

Tags: html, css

I guess this problem is very simple to solve, but I don't know what to search for..

I want to have always the same space between words in multiple lines. Like invisible tables, but I want to avoid tables.

Example:

```
01.01.1999       Text
02.01.1999       Text gdfgf
03.01.99         Text gfghdh
```

How would you do this?

PS: I need a solution which applies on each row, because the data is delivered row per row through serverside scripts.

Comment: If the information you are displaying is data, a table might be the appropriate way to display it - so you can mark it up with the correct headers etc.

Comment: Or if you have these one-rule-data you could put some `span` tags in a div and add some padding to them.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `<pre>` tag, unless you're looking for special formatting within each row. Description lists `<dl>` maybe another option in that case.

```
<pre>
01.01.1999       Text
02.01.1999       Text gdfgf
03.01.99         Text gfghdh
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically you could place a span (with the same class) around the text that you want to pad out and give the span the same width so that it pushes the other text out.
for example:

```
span{
width:100px;
display: block;
float:left;
}
```